# Is it possible to disable auto lock in a mobile device when a specific page of my web app is presented?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, pusher

I'm working on a mobile web app in which I need Pusher's javascript server to keep on getting triggers such that the page will keep on getting updates.

Unfortunately, the auto screen lock pauses the procedure.

Is there a way to cause the mobile browser to prevent the device from auto locking?

Comment: The stock (Android) browser on the device? Don't think so. If you build your own apk that just contains a webview that you are displaying your web app in, then yes, just acquire a wakelock. No idea about ios though.

Comment: In iOS it is about the same Tim said. In the stock Safari you can't change device settings. But if you made an actual app instead of a lazy app you could have more control over the accelerometer.

Comment: @Tim On Android, I'm talking about Firefox, since the stock browser doesn't support websockets anyway. btw, is it possible to set the browsers (Firefox/Safari) not to auto lock device?

Comment: as a workaround : is there a way to execute a refresh or an ajax request when reactivating device after auto lock?

Comment: These guys have already answered:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504238/javascript-code-to-prevent-screensaver-from-starting

Comment: @Barnash - do you even understand the question? Please dont put irrelevant links here.