# How to keep an HTML page active

Tags: javascript, html, flash

We have the following problem:

We're developing a browser-based flash application for video calls. The problem with that application is that when you are talking with somebody the display of your PC/Mac starts to fade out and a couple of minutes later the screensaver appears (if such is present).

How to keep the page active, so that the PC/Mac does not enter in screensaver mode?

This should be done, using *JavaScript* only, because the flash-part of the application is a *JavaScript* based API and we do **NOT** have access to the *flash* directly.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** can I put a small and invisible flash APP on that page that keeps the machine from sleeping?

Comment: You do not have that kind of control of the host computer using JavaScript (thankfully).

Comment: Cheapest solution is to put a notice: "Please disable your screensaver or move your mouse periodically" :s

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504238/javascript-code-to-prevent-screensaver-from-starting

Comment: And can I put a small and invisible flash APP on that page that keeps the machine from sleeping?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NoSleep.js
https://github.com/richtr/NoSleep.js

Prevent display sleep and enable wake lock in all Android and iOS web browsers.