# In HTML5, how can I keep an Android device’s screen on?

Tags: android, html

We are developing an App in HTML5 using jQuery.

Is there a way/method, in JavaScript or another technology, to keep the screen "on"?

Comment: Not likely. This sort of things require a special permission from the user installing the app. I'm no expert though.

Comment: If you are creating an actual install-able application then yes you can keep an android device on using wake lock. If you are just developing a mobile web page, then no, you can not keep the screen on. Should it be the first situation I recommend searching here for wake lock as this has been answered many times before.

Comment: Yes I beleive there is. You must create an interface between your javascript methods and your app. One of these methods can reference, and hold, the WAKE_LOCK. There area few examples of JavaScript to Android interfaces. You expose certain methods to the JavaScript.

Comment: Check my suggestion listed below => http://stackoverflow.com/a/29796071/1976820

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to ONLY write javascript or other web code to keep the screen on, without writing at least a little java code.

To explain why I am so certain, if you are developing a web app through html5 you MUST use a WebView as the main "screen" of your application to host your html,javascript code. So your "web code" does not directly run in the application but uses a View as its holder. As you can guess you can't just lock the screen from some code that is not even running in the native part.

I can provide a very easy and simple way to keep the screen on if you are not an expert in android programming. In the first activity, that uses the WebView I guess, add in `onCreate` after `super`:

`getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`

Comment: Guys, thanks a lot for your answers.
I'm having a map application, is there a way maybe to simulate map movement or map touch and by that the screen will keep being on?
Thanks again.

Comment: If not possible i will use PhoneGap and implement "10s" Idea.

Comment: Phonegap is a very good solution in implementing this kind of things. I have been experimenting with Phonegap too in some applications and it gives a very good support for implementing native parts through web code. I have not created anything that involves google maps with phonegap, but you must take something under consideration. In android there is some privacy policy with map-application keys that need to be done in order for the application to view the map and I am not sure if this can be done through phonegap, you should google it first.

Comment: Hi, sorry i can't not enough rep yet.

Comment: you added the question, how is this possible? :S

Comment: Not the vote up, doesn't the confirm tick bellow that appear? The one that asks a question must confirm an answer, if it is satisfactory, for the convinience of others. The vote is for an outsider to mark a question as important or an answer as useful. If you ask questions you should confirm one of the answers afterwards, because there is a certain ratio and you might not get answers if that ratio is not good enough.

Answer (score 33):

I think there is another way doing it without any java code. You can add a video of 1 second with infinite repeat and hidden and it will do the trick. I have read it somewhere but i don't remember where.

Maybe you could use one of the blank videos below:

1. https://github.com/esc0rtd3w/blank-intro-videos
2. https://github.com/kud/blank-video

**IT WORKS!**

Comment: This works! I generated an "empty" 1-second video with `ffmpeg -r 20 -t 1 -s 1x1 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -i /dev/zero noop.mpeg` and put it under a `<video loop>` tag. Trigger `play()` from a touch event and the screen stays on while the tab is focused. `pause()` the video to allow the screen to sleep again.

Comment: Good to know it helped

Comment: Pro: no user config setting needed. Con: screen will go off eventually, when the battery gets empty, which may be annoying for the user.

Comment: @Roland This is of course a workaround if you are on a web environment. On a hybrid or native app this may not be useful.

Comment: Awesome trick! Would it be sensible from CPU use standpoint to make the video a bit longer, since one-pixel video with no change in color probably doesn't affect the file size much? I would theorize that playing a long video instead of starting the same video from beginning every second would eat a bit less CPU, since in both cases the video is running ~ 100 % of the time, but there must be some additional work involved in restarting the video.

Comment: Did not work on iPhones, but worked on various Android phones I tested.

Answer (score 8):

Google's [WebVR polyfill](https://github.com/googlevr/webvr-polyfill) has a [way to do this](https://github.com/googlevr/webvr-polyfill/blob/master/src/wakelock.js) on Chrome. It basically creates a tiny video (with a data URL, so no extra downloads needed) and loops it.

It seems like a hack, so I wouldn't be surprised if it's not reliable in the future.

They have code that achieves the same thing on iOS too, by triggering a location update.

Here's the relevant code for Android:

```js
var Util={};
Util.base64 = function(mimeType, base64) {
  return 'data:' + mimeType + ';base64,' + base64;
};

var video = document.createElement('video');
  video.setAttribute('loop', '');

  function addSourceToVideo(element, type, dataURI) {
    var source = document.createElement('source');
    source.src = dataURI;
    source.type = 'video/' + type;
    element.appendChild(source);
  }

  addSourceToVideo(video,'webm', Util.base64('video/webm', 'GkXfo0AgQoaBAUL3gQFC8oEEQvOBCEKCQAR3ZWJtQoeBAkKFgQIYU4BnQI0VSalmQCgq17FAAw9CQE2AQAZ3aGFtbXlXQUAGd2hhbW15RIlACECPQAAAAAAAFlSua0AxrkAu14EBY8WBAZyBACK1nEADdW5khkAFVl9WUDglhohAA1ZQOIOBAeBABrCBCLqBCB9DtnVAIueBAKNAHIEAAIAwAQCdASoIAAgAAUAmJaQAA3AA/vz0AAA='));
  addSourceToVideo(video, 'mp4', Util.base64('video/mp4', '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'));

video.play();
```

Comment: Hmm I'm getting a DOMException in video.play().catch() when trying to use the base64 sources you provided. It does work when I set the src to http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4

Answer (score 6):

The future answer - because it's experimental now - is to use the new API called: [Screen Wake Lock API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Wake_Lock_API)

I think you can mix it with previous workaround answers

```js
// Create a reference for the Wake Lock.
let wakeLock = null;

// create an async function to request a wake lock
try {
  wakeLock = await navigator.wakeLock.request('screen');
  statusElem.textContent = 'Wake Lock is active!';
} catch (err) {
  // try other solutions here ...
}
```

You can follow the support of this feature [here](https://caniuse.com/wake-lock)

Comment: Great solution! As of Aug 2023 any browser but Firefox supports it. I tried the workaround by playing a video but this doesn't work in FF either. Any ideas how to keep the device alive when using FF?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest method is to go to the Settings, Developer Options, and to select "Stay awake while charging". No need to code anything!

This supposes that OP wants to keep the screen on *while connected to an external power source*, which is reasonable, otherwise no clever coding will prevent the screen from going off soon when the internal battery drains empty.

The external power source can be as simple as a portable usb battery. When that eventually gets empty, the device will go to sleep as usual, but will remain functional on its internal battery.

I found this solution here:
[posting about keeping the screen on](http://www.greenbot.com/article/2463970/how-to-keep-your-android-phones-screen-on-longer.html)

Comment: This does not help on production

Comment: @HerbiShtini Why not? If you want to keep the screen ON for a long time, you might well need external power.

Comment: because this needs for each user to go and do this manually and most of the users won't bother doing it. So you have achieved nothing here. It is not reliable that is why!

Comment: @HerbiShtini OK, OK, but all of these users might want to plug in external power. In my project, I wanted to track GPS on my bike ride, with screen continuously on, which is basically similar to a navigator in a car. Without external power: no fun.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the device on does not depend on the OS but on the browser. Chrome is in the process of implementing Wake Lock API, but it is still experimental.

Until fully available, there is a way to mock the api by playing a base64 video in the background. This locks the sleep mode with all browsers.

You can find a webcomponent implementation here https://github.com/madeInLagny/mil-no-sleep