# How to keep screen on with a webpage

Tags: android, ios, browser, screen

I have a web app that streams text to a webpages, used for remote text interpretation.
I there any fix to keep the users screens on while they are on the webpage?

The concern is most for mobile clients like iOS and Android, but to a smaller extent OSX and Windows

Comment: You can't in a web app.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529247/in-html5-how-can-i-keep-an-android-device-s-screen-on for tip on Android platform.

Answer (score 9):

There's a trick: if the web page plays a web media file, the device will keep the screen lightopened.
A js library NoSleep.js relies on this trick to provide what you're looking for.

Check this  https://github.com/richtr/NoSleep.js

Regards,
Cedric.

Answer (score 2):

If wy web app you mean a real one, where nothing is installed on the client's device, you will notice this is impossible.
To use some devices features, like lock screen on, you must have some code running natively on the device.

Like stated in: [In HTML5, how can I keep an Android device’s screen on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529247/in-html5-how-can-i-keep-an-android-devices-screen-on)

If you want that kind of interaction with the device (lock screen on) you will likely have to write some cocoa/java/winRT code, and publish the application on targeted stores (apple, google, windows).
From there customers will be able to download your application which will run the web app behind.

Answer (score -4):

Add `android:keepScreenOn="true"` in your layout xml

Comment: He was asking about web applications not about native applications.