# Android web page session endless lifetime

Tags: android, html, ajax, session, android-wifi

I want to show telemetry data from web server via WiFi to html page with AJAX (without writing native android application).

So Android browser have to show HTML page forever without turn off.

Is it good, or is there some troubles with session length, itc?

For disable LDC-off I found NoSleep.js *[How to keep screen on with a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153674/how-to-keep-screen-on-with-a-webpage)*
I hope it can also turn it on according to telemetry signals.

Answer (score 0):

Did you looked into firebase real-time database.
It uses publisher subscriber model, which is very handy for real-time data.

Comment: thank you, but in this project I investigate using ESP web server + android browser (lightweight, clean, pure JS)  without additional software